# Excel - Automatically fill cell with specific month and year when I type in the day of the month in the same cell

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to auto include a specific month and year in a cell when I type in the day and have the cell in the format 00/00/0000. Is there a way to accomplish this in VBA?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

I attempted this but it does not seem to be picking up the date cell containing the month and year:

Sub AddMonthYearToDate()
Dim dateCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim dateString As String
Dim month As String
Dim year As String
Dim targetCell As Range

```
' Define the cell containing the month and year (change this to your actual cell)
Set dateCell = Range("G1")

' Define the range where you type the number (change this to your actual range)
Set inputRange = Range("L2:M100")

' Loop through each cell in the input range
For Each targetCell In inputRange
    ' Check if the input cell is not empty
    If targetCell.Value <> "" Then
        ' Extract the month and year from the date cell
        dateText = dateCell.Value
        
        ' Parse the month and year from the date text
        month = Split(dateText, " ")(1)
        year = Split(dateText, " ")(2)
        
        ' Create the final date string
        dateString = "01/" & Format(DateValue(month & " 1, " & year), "mm/yyyy") & "/" & targetCell.Value
        
        ' Check if the resulting date is valid
        If IsDate(dateString) Then
            ' Set the formatted date in the input cell
            targetCell.Value = Format(CDate(dateString), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid date. Please enter a valid number in the input cell.", vbExclamation
        End If
    End If
Next targetCell
```

End Sub

Comment: If `Range("G1")` is formatted `00/00/0000` then you need to split on `/` .`month = Split(dateText, "/")(1)`

Comment: Observation: a lot of the code inside the loop doesn't need to be as `dateCell` doesn't change.

Comment: Can you screenshot your sheet (or a mock up of it) and add it to your question - so we better understand the inputs?

Comment: [LINK](https://lreme-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/joe_lremeestates_com/EQfj_R21XfhDlz6zV49QUP0BlQjWb5SzEOlUKyDysjBPLQ?e=lfrcjU) _italic_ **bold** 'code'

Comment: Thanks @CLR, I've provided the link.
 - cell F1 is the date cell and cells J2:L100 is my input range